# Get the id of a the item that is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html code:

```
<b class = "edit" id = "foo1">FOO</b>
<b class = "edit" id = "foo2">FOO2</b>
<b class = "edit" id = "foo3">FOO3</b>
```

And I have this code in jQuery:

```
$('b.edit').click(function(){
    //GET THE ID OF THE b.edit: e.g foo1, foo2, foo3
    $('.editP').focus();
});
```

How can I get the `id` value of the `b.edit`, as there are multiple instances of b.edit, and I want to get the specific `id` of the one clicked? How can I do this?

Thanks, Sorry, I am pretty new to javascript.

Comment: What framework do You use? jQuery?

Comment: All this people advocating `$(this).attr("id")` instead of `this.id` make me very, very sad.

Comment: @Domenic I can see your point ..... **IF** the OP was just getting the id and nothing else - however the very next instruction is to call a jQuery  method ... (i know you going to say that you can use the focus method without jQuery - but it could be any jQuery method)

Comment: @ManseUK a jQuery method on a completely different element.

Comment: @Domenic :-( *walks off to grab some stronger glasses ......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming from your sample code that you're using jQuery? If so you can get the id as follows:

```
$('b.edit').click(function(){
 this.id;
});
```

EDIT:

The direct reference to the attribute is indeed more efficient if all that is required is simply the id.

Also can be obtained from the jQuery object:

```
$('b.edit').click(function(){
 $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5bQQT/

Comment: Why use two function calls with `$(this).attr('id')` when a direct attribute reference works faster with `this.id`?  This is one place where jQuery is LESS efficient than straight javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Try with this:

```
$('b.edit').click(function(e){ //When you use an event is better
                               //send the event variable to the 
                               //binding function.
    var id = e.target.id; //get the id of the clicked element.
   /*do your stuff*/
    $('.editP').focus();
});
```

Comment: **always** is a little strong for an **optional** argument

Comment: Yep is an optional, but for a newbie is better that take it  as mandatory. :D

Comment: Not really ... read this -> http://api.jquery.com/event.target/ `$(this)` and `event.target` could be different ....

Comment: In general I do not like using $(this) due to abuse of the $() function . But you're right are differents, although in this case e.target.id fulfills its purpose well.

Comment: totally agree - was just adding some detail as to how they are different .. and that it is an optional argument .... :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.edit').live('click', function() {
    alert( this.id );
});
```

**Sample**
http://jsfiddle.net/ck2Xk/

Comment: Oops. @ _Domenic_: "All this people advocating `$(this).attr("id")` instead of `this.id` make me very, very sad."

Answer (score 2):

try this. You can use keyword "this" to retrieve the attr ID...

`$('b.edit').click(function(){`
    `alert($(this).attr("id"));`
 `});`

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.edit').click(function(){
   var theId = $(this).attr('id');
}
```

This will get you the ID of anything clicked with a class of `.edit`

Answer (score 1):

When passing a `click` handler in JQuery, you actually have a reference to something called an [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/). This event object has a property called [`target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/), which is a reference to the element that was clicked.

```
$('b.edit').click(function(eventObject){
    eventObject.target // this is the element that was clicked.
});
```

Since you have a reference to the target element, you can do whatever you like. In this case, you could just access `eventObject.target.id`.

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

More clearly:

```
$('b.edit').live('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    // in this scope this.id works too
    // var id = this.id;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody has shown the simplest method yet that doesn't even need jQuery to get the id:

```
$('.edit').click(function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

I never understand why people use jQuery for getting simple attributes which involves two jQuery function calls (and a bunch of overhead to create a jQuery object) instead of one direct attribute reference.

Comment: OK, removed `.live()` as it's an irrelevant part of what this code block is illustrating.  Since most of the world isn't on 1.7 yet, a lot of people are still using `.live()` and it works just fine in 1.7 too and will likely continue to work for awhile as it's in widespread use.  I know people should move to `.on()` in 1.7+, but folks seem to go a little overboard on that here on SO, particularly in an irrelevant part of the demo code.  And, if you wanted a code demo that worked in 1.4, 1.5, 1.6 and 1.7, you couldn't use `.on()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is called event delegation in Javascript. More info can be found in Zakas blog http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/30/event-delegation-in-javascript/

The idea in few words is `you attache the event to a parent node and then waiting for some event on the child node`. In the example below I attach the onclick event to the document itself. Then inside the event handler you will write a switch statement to check the clicked element id, then do what you want to do for that element

```
document.onclick = function(event){
    //IE doesn't pass in the event object
    event = event || window.event;

    //IE uses srcElement as the target
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;    

    switch(target.id){
        case "foo1":
            foo1();
            break;
        case "foo2":
            foo2();
            break;
        case "foo3":
            foo3();
            break;
        //others?
    }
};


//some dummy handlers
var foo1 = function(){ 
    alert("You clicked foo1");
    };

var foo2 = function(){ 
    alert("You clicked foo2");
    };

var foo3 = function(){ 
    alert("You clicked foo3");
    };
```

For how to implement event delegation in jQuery you can check http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Comment: Straight from your link -> "As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method"

Comment: oh my bad, this is the old way

Answer (score -1):

Even though this is not a real answer to your question. I will try to explain why what your asking is not the way to go. Since you are new especially, since learing bad practices could be hard to unlearn. Allways try to search for an ID before finding an element by its Class. Also try to avoid giving every element the same class (and in this case ID to), just give it an encapsulating parent.

Furthermore, the `id` of an element is really specific and should preferably used to find / select / bind events to. An `id` should usually be unique for this to work, so in your case a couple of things could be optimized, lets say like:

```
<div id="foo"> 
  <b id="1">Foo</b>
  <b id="2">Other foo</b>
  <b id="3">Some foo</b>
</div>
```

Now if you want to know which  was clicked there are multiple ways to accomplish it, but a nice one is simply binding a parent its children (i.e `<div id="foo"> .. </div>`). This way you can alter the structure of your  pretty fast, without changing all the classes and id's.

With jQuery you can get the attribute id using the `.attr()` function. However I told you the `id` was pretty specific and thus has its own rights in javascript world. An `id` can also be directly targeted (`'DOMelement.id'`, but this would be too much to explain for now)

In two ways the `<b>` can be targetted:

Example a)

```
var b_elements = $("#foo").children();
```

Example b)

```
var b_elements = $("#foo").find('b');
```

We can add jQuery (or javascript events) to these found elements. The nice thing about jQuery is that it simplifies alot of work. So in your case if you would like to know an `id` of a certain clicked `<b>` field you could use a very verbose way:

```
b_elements.click(function()
{
  var clicked_element = $(this);
  alert(clicked_element.attr('id'));
});
```

Verbose because you can do it much much shorter, but who cares about a few bytes when your learning and this makes remembering functions and events alot easier. Say you wanted to get the class `edit` by finding the  where you knew the id that was clicked:

```
b_elements.click(function()
{
  var clicked_element = $(this);
  alert(clicked_element.attr('class'));
});
```

And to conclude, the id of an element is ment to be unique because it makes searching through big documents alot faster. Also don't forget to look and learn plain javascript, as it helps coding in jQuery alot too, but not the other way around. Your given question would require a `for` loop in plain javascript since it cannot do a lookup by class nor id nor have they have a common parent.

Good luck with learning :)