# jQuery find the element with same tag on click

Tags: jquery, html, attr

i have a following scenario in my html page i want to select the attribute of the clicked element

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="section1">
         <div id="1">1</div>
         <div id="2">2</div>
         <div id="3">3</div>
         <div id="4">4</div>
         <div id="5">5</div>
         <div id="6">6</div>
         <div id="7">7</div>
         <div id="8">8</div>
         <div id="9">9</div>
         <div id="10">10</div>
     </div>
     <div class="section2">
     </div>
</div>
```

Following is my jQuery on click

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.section1:div').click(function() {
            alert($(this).attr("id"))
        })
    });

</script>
```

Comment: See this --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159497/get-the-id-of-a-the-item-that-is-clicked

Comment: What is the question or problem?

Comment: Your selector should be `'.section1>div'`.

Comment: (Also, avoid numeric IDs. They're invalid in HTML4 and cause browser inconsistencies.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your jQuery selector, replace the ':' in ':div' with a space, indicating you want to select the DIV elements.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.section1 div').click(function () {
            alert($(this).attr("id"))
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: this will give me value from `attr("id")` of the clicked div, right? Great it just worked correctly as i needed, i asked this i am completely new in jQuery and my training is in progress

Answer (score 2):

Your `jQuery` selector should be:

```
$('.section1 > div')
```

`:` is a filter, e.g. `$('.checkbox:checked')` - will select all elements with class checkbox and filter checked from the set. Read more on jQuery selectors [`here`](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Also, avoid using `language` attribute for your script tag, - it is approx. 10 years long as it is deprecated.

Comment: Hi, your solution is also correct, thanks for your quick response

Answer (score 1):

.section1:div the colon is wrong. Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.section1 div').click(function() {
         alert($(this).attr("id"))
     });
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you mean?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.section1 div').click(function() {
        alert(this.id)
    })
});
```

But if you want to have a second selection, you can't use the same ID's.

Use this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="section1">
         <div data-info="1">1</div>
         <div data-info="2">2</div>
         <div data-info="3">3</div>
         <div data-info="4">4</div>
         <div data-info="5">5</div>
         <div data-info="6">6</div>
         <div data-info="7">7</div>
         <div data-info="8">8</div>
         <div data-info="9">9</div>
         <div data-info="10">10</div>
     </div>
     <div class="section2">
         <div data-info="1">1</div>
         <div data-info="2">2</div>
         <div data-info="3">3</div>
         <div data-info="4">4</div>
         <div data-info="5">5</div>
         <div data-info="6">6</div>
         <div data-info="7">7</div>
         <div data-info="8">8</div>
         <div data-info="9">9</div>
         <div data-info="10">10</div>
     </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.section1 div[data-info]').click(function() {
        alert($(this).data("info") + " clicked within selection " + $(this).parent().attr("class"));
    })
});
```

The `.section1 div[data-info]` selects all `DIV` elements within the `.selection1` which have an attribute named `data-info`. This can be done using the `[]`.