# How to detect current element id in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have some HTML codes:

```
<input type="button" id="btn1" class="myButton" value="Button 1"/>
<input type="button" id="btn2" class="myButton" value="Button 2"/>
```

I need to run a jQuery function whenever user click each button, and I have to do it using their class.

```
$('.myButton').click(function() {
   // do something
});
```

But what I should to do, depends on the current element Id.

My question is that how can I detect which element called this function? I need to know its id.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the id of a the item that is clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159497/get-the-id-of-a-the-item-that-is-clicked)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use `this` to access current element and then `this.id` will give you the `id` of the current element.

```
$(document).on('click', '.myButton', function(e) {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 27):

If you want to keep in jquery context, you could use this snippet:

```
$('.myButton').click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

With this way you are a bit more flexible.

Answer (score 4):

With jQuery i found this working:

```
$(this).prop('id')
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pcU7h/).
You can just use the attr() method to get the id of the clicked element as you bind a click callback to EVERY element with .myButton class.

Comment: Please add an explanation and code as well. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer - *Provide context for links*

Comment: Thank you andreapier. The point was $(this) ... 
Also thank you all other friends.

Answer (score 1):

`this` in the event handler is the element that was clicked:

```
$('.myButton').click(function() {

   if (this.id === "btn1") {
       ...
   }    

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.myButton').on('click',(e)=> {

 if (e.target.id === "btn1") {
     ...
}    

});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.