# Get id on click

Tags: jquery, css, class, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get the id of a the item that is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159497/get-the-id-of-a-the-item-that-is-clicked)

I have multiple divs with buttons i would like to, on click of the button, display the id of the div next to the button (only in the div where the button was clicked).
http://jsfiddle.net/VXLXw/1/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var $p = $(this).parent(),
        id = $p.attr('id');
    if (!$p.find('.id').size()) { 
        $p.append('<span class="id">'+id+'</span>');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dPhTa/5

Now updated so it won't repeatedly append.

Comment: how can i stop it from repeating once the button has been clicked

Comment: @foshoeiyyy: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947218/in-jquery-is-there-any-way-to-only-bind-a-click-once